# Get all aliases from KeyManagers without knowing the key type

Tags: java, ssl, key, keystore

I've a `KeyManager` array and I need to get all aliases from it. So I was going to call the method `String[] getClientAliases(String keyType, Principal[] issuers)` of `X509KeyManager` interface where I put `null` for `issuers` but I don't know what I should put as `keyType`, since I've any information about that.

Just for information, I'm doing that to build a `KeyStore` object from `KeyManager[]` array. After getting all aliases, for each alias I call `getCertificateChain` and `getPrivateKey`, before put both results as en entry in the keyStore. Maybe you know other ways to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure in which situation you'd be able to get hold of a `KeyManager` instance without being able to get hold of the `KeyStore` instance next to it (since the former would generally have just been initialised with the former, or at least under code usually within the same people's control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key types are listed in the [Java™ Cryptography Architecture
Standard Algorithm Name Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#jssenames), in a table towards the end ("*Additional JSSE Standard Names*"): RSA, DSA, DH_RSA, DH_DSA, EC, EC_EC and EC_RSA.

Note that you might be able to get instances of `PrivateKey` this way, and re-construct some instance of `KeyStore`, but you might not be able to save that keystore with the content of the private key in all cases. `PrivateKey` is a class representing a private key, with method allowing it to be used as such. It doesn't necessarily contain the private key material, for example if this is a private key obtained from a PKCS#11 hardware token.